# Is government housing for an undocumented resident a risk?

Tags: united-states, immigration, virginia

I live next to a government aided apartment complex (called APAH). I know of some people that would really benefit from living there with the reduced rent. The problem is that I don’t know if they are here in the US legally and I don’t want to ask them if they are because it’s pretty uncomfortable. But I also don’t want to tell them to apply because they could get deported from giving their information to the housing complex who could turn them into ICE. So my question is, does government aided housing require the residents to be legal residents? And if they find out someone doesn’t have legal documents, are they obligated to record their information with the government, which could end up in their getting deported?

Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2):

> does government aided housing require the residents to be legal
>   residents?

Yes.

> And if they find out someone doesn’t have legal documents, are they
>   obligated to record their information with the government, which could
>   end up in their getting deported?

There are not legally required to do so, by statute anyway, but are allowed to do so and may be encouraged to do so. An application by an undocumented immigrant could also be misinterpreted as attempted welfare fraud, which is a crime.

Comment: @Putvi Failing to disclose disqualifying information in an application for a welfare benefit is usually a crime. *See, e.g., In re Sands*, 18 Cal.3d 851 (1977).

Comment: @Putvi Hence, "misinterpreted."

Comment: @Putvi I am not disagreeing with that fact, but I am saying that as a practical matter, applying for benefits when you are not a citizen is likely to trigger a criminal investigation and that the mere application itself is likely to be construed as a representation of belief of eligibility.